# Sort by Date not working as expecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I know this is not how this site should work but I'm really low in time and I need to fix this. However I dont understand why this is not working.

We have elements with this kind of structure

```
<li>
  <title>
  <date>
  <content>
</li>
<li>
  ...
</li>
etc..
```

And this is my sort function :

```
$('li').sort(function(a, b) {
    var aDate = $(a).find('.itemDate').text();
    var bDate = $(b).find('.itemDate').text();
    return new Date(bDate).getTime() - new Date(aDate).getTime();
}).appendTo('ul');
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is it due to the fact that the return refere to a date and not to the whole element ?

[You have a JsFiddle there.](https://jsfiddle.net/9pk1ajev/1/)

### Edit :

Thanks to a people comment on a deleted answer I was able to fix it ! It was due to the presence of "Invalide Date" among the `<date>` elements. Thank you who ever you were ! :)

Comment: `.itemDate` returns a valid element?

Comment: The code in your sort function doesn't match the XML structure you've provided at all. Where is your element with `class="itemDate"` and what does its text content look like?

Comment: @ipohfly Just have a look at the Fiddle :)